# Why this instance variable is not incrementing?

Tags: ruby

This short code is working when I'm using class variable `@@points` instead of `@points`. I wonder why it's happening like this? Someone can explain me? It looks like `@points` is always `nil`.

```
class Game

  @points = 0

  def start

    until @points == 10
      puts "Guess number between 0 and 10:" 
      num = gets.chomp.to_i
      break if @points == 0
      guess_number(num)
      puts "Your score is: #{@points}"

    end

  end

  def guess_number(num)
    @points += 1 if num == rand(0..10)
  end

end

game = Game.new
game.start
```

Comment: A minuscule point: `gets.chomp.to_i` is often written without `chomp`: `gets.to_i`. That's because `"123".to_i`, `"123\n".to_i` and `"123X456abc".to_i` all return `123`. See [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_i), which includes, "Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `@points` is a class instance variable, and to access it from within the instance method's scope you'd have to either do

```
self.class.instance_variable_get(:@points)
```

or define an `attr_accessor` in `Game`'s singleton_class

```
class Game; class << self; attr_accessor :points; end; end
```

and then you'd be able to do

```
self.class.points
```

But neither of these is what you really want.

> code is working when I'm using class variable `@@points` instead of
>   `@points`

It is working, because you do have access to class variable from within a scope of an instance methods.

> It looks like `@points` is always `nil`

It is always `nil`, because you never defined an instance variable `@points`, but, as said, class instance variable.

So these three things are different (you could read up something about Ruby scoping - do not mix with AR scopes):

- class variable
- class instance variable
- instance variable

To solve it there are many ways, but if you want to keep it on the instance level, wrap `@points` into a method:

```
def points
  @points ||= 0
end
```

And then use it as `points` - now it'll work as you are expecting.

Comment: If OP didn't want to expose the points outside the class, wouldn't it just be easier to implement a constructor that sets `@points = 0`?

Comment: @pjs as i said, there's quit a few ways to do it, so it's up to OP to choose, but of course, it's one of them :)

Comment: It may be misleading to say that the value of a class instance variable  cannot be obtained within an instance's scope, since that can be done with  `self.class.instance_variable_get(:@points)` (as you well-know).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer by Andrey Deineko. I came up with such solution to use instance variable here.

```
class Game

  def initialize
    @points = 0
  end

  def start

    until points == 10
      puts "Guess number between 0 and 10:" 
      num = gets.chomp.to_i
      break if points == 10
      guess_number(num)
      puts "Your score is: #{points}"

    end

  end

  private

  def guess_number(num)
    if num == rand(0..10)
      increment_points
    end
  end

  def points
    @points
  end

  def increment_points
    @points += 1
  end

end

game = Game.new
game.start
```

Comment: The hazard of this approach is that a user who pokes into your class will find they can call `increment_points` directly without playing the game.  If you want to use an instance variable, add an `initialize` method to the class where the `@points` get initialized to 0 when you create a `Game.new` instance.

Comment: It seems to be good idea. I edited my anwser and also I made some of methods private.

Comment: You're also subverting canonical Ruby standards by naming the getter something other than what attr_reader would name it. Just something to consider.

Comment: I changed it to just `points` method not `get_points`. Thanks for your advice.